# Non-invokable OkObjectResult cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to change a view based application into an API.
Working off this project [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36804.asp-net-core-mvc-authentication-and-role-based-authorization-with-asp-net-core-identity.aspx#Introduction).

I can't return an `OkObjectResult`.  Why is this, and why has ASP moved to `IActionResult` vs `ActionResult`?

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<ApplicationRoleListViewModel> model = new List<ApplicationRoleListViewModel>();
    model = roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new ApplicationRoleListViewModel
    {
        RoleName = r.Name,
        Id = r.Id,
        Description = r.Description,
        NumberOfUsers = r.Users.Count
    }).ToList();
    return OkObjectResult(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`OkObjectResult` is a class not a method, you need to new it up: `return new OkObjectResult(model)` or use the [helper method that exists on the controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Ok_System_Object_):

```
return Ok(model);
```